# Apache 2, mod_fastcgi, REST: Handle requests to different URIs with the same application

Tags: apache, rest, mod-fastcgi

I am trying to develop a RESTful service using Apache 2 and mod_fastcgi as my transport and security layer.

What I am trying to achieve is that a C++-application is called when a request is made. Then I want to use the HTTP method and the URI to decide (inside the application) which of the (internal) resources should be accessed and in which way.

Calling my C++-FastCGI application works (located @ /var/www/html/foo/fastcgi_test). But only with a specific URI - the URI where my binary is located:

If I open http://127.0.0.1/foo/fastcgi_test in a browser my application runs and returns a html test page like I want.
Trying e.g. http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar returns a page with a 404. But I would like the same application to be called (fastcgi_test).

My configuration (so far) looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>   
  FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi    
  <Location /foo>
    SetHandler fastcgi-script   
  </Location>    
  FastCgiServer /var/www/html/foo/fastcgi_test -flush    
</IfModule>
```

I read the [mod_fastcgi manual](http://www.fastcgi.com/om_archive/servers/apache/apache-fastcgi/mod_fastcgi.html) and dug through the Apache manuals, but I can't find the right hint. It seems I don't seach for the right key word. 
As I am very new to Apache configuration I maybe/hopefully just miss the right starting point.

How do I configure Apache/mod_fastcgi to send requests to a "branch of URIs" to the same FastCGI process? Can somebody provide a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use an alias. I also moved the FastCGI program out of the content area of Apache into a separate directory (/var/www/fastcgi).

My solution looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi
  <Directory /var/www/fastcgi>
    SetHandler fastcgi-script
  </Directory>
  <Location "/foo">
    Require all granted
  </Location>
  FastCgiServer /var/www/fastcgi/fastcgi_test -flush
  AliasMatch "/foo(.*)" "/var/www/fastcgi/fastcgi_test"
</IfModule>
```